# Powershell command to return Chrome's download folder as a string

Tags: powershell, google-chrome

I'm looking for a command for Powershell that will return a String containing the filepath used for its configured Downloads folder.

I'm trying to do something along the lines of a Get-Content for $settings.download.default_directory but not getting results, not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Could you post what you've done so far?

Comment: I'm pretty darn new to Powershell so I have no idea if I'm even going down the right road

As a test I'm just trying to Write the output but I know i'm starting fundamentally wrong. I thought It would be something like:

Write-Output (Get-Content -Path $settings.download.default_directory)

I get the following return:

Get-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '$null'.
At line:1 char:15

Comment: Convert the prefs file from json.

Comment: You can find the path to the profile preferences for a user in `%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`, you'll need to check for each Windows account. There will be a Profile file containing JSON for each profile a user has configured. They start numbering after the first. e.g. Profile then Profile 2 etc. The value you are looking for is `download -> default_directory` and you can also get the profile name under `profile -> name` in those JSON files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(EDIT: My other post has a working solution. I'll leave this one here in case you find it useful.)

I can get you some of the way there, but not all the way.

Assuming you're referring to Chrome on Windows, it typically stores its preferences in "C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences". So you'd start with something like:

```
$prefs = Get-Content "C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences"
```

(Replace "[user]" with your account name, obviously.)

"Preferences" is a text file consisting of a single, gigantic string of comma-separated data. This is where it specifies my download directory, for example:

```
,"download":{"default_directory":"C:\\Users\\Matt\\Desktop",
```

Your next step might be to do '$prefs | Select-String [something...]' to parse that file for that string. However, I don't know how to do that part. It's a matter of telling it: "look for ',"download":', then pull out everything from the comma before 'download' until the next comma."

Once you have that, you can then split on double quotes to isolate the directory path, then remove the double slashes. So, assuming you have the above string in a variable called "$download", it might be something like:

```
$download = $download.Split('"')[5]
$download = $download.Replace('\\','\')
$download
```

Or you can do the above in a single line like this:

```
($download.Split('"')[5]).Replace('\\','\')
```

Btw, be super careful with quotes on this task! Since Chrome uses double quotes extensively in that preferences file, be sure to always wrap stuff in single quotes otherwise it's not going to work.

Also, as side note: in PowerShell, text in single quotes isn't parsed whereas text in double quotes is. So that's another reason why we should be wrapping stuff in single quotes here: we want the text as a simple string. If the string happened to contain, say, "$path" and we wrapped it in double-quotes, it would interpret that as the existing system variable "$path" and try to do something with it, which would be...undesirable!

Answer (score 0):

I just realized there's no need to mess around with 'Select-String' - the prefs file is already comma separated, so we can just split on commas and search for the download dir based on a partial string.

This should work (change '[user]' in the first line to your account):

```
$prefs = Get-Content 'C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences' # Create variable containing Chrome's preferences file for [user]
$prefs = $prefs.Split(',') # Split the file on commas (this converts the comma-separated string into an array of values)
$downloadString = $prefs | Where-Object {$_ -like '*download":*'} # Locate the string we want by searching on part of it that we already know will be there (note the '-like' and the wildcard asterisks)
$downloadString = $downloadString.Split('"')[5] # Split the string on double quotes and select the sixth item in the resulting array (arrays produced by 'Split' start at zero), which is the path we're looking for
$downloadString = $downloadString.Replace('\\','\') # Replace the double slashes in the path with single slashes
$downloadString # Print the result to the screen
```

There are various ways you can compress that down to just a couple of lines, but I figured since you're new, this way would make it easier to see how it works.

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

Chrome uses a `Preferences` file (no extension) to store the downloads folder path in a setting called `default_directory` **IF the user has set up a custom path in Chrome's settings**.
This Preferences file is a JSON file and can be easily read by PowerShell.

When the user has not set up a custom path, this setting is not available in the Preferences file and Chrome will use whatever is set for the current user in Windows.

To get that you will either need to read the path from registry, or use the Shell.Application COM object.

Both are handled in the code below:

```
$prefsPath = "$env:localappdata\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences"
if (Test-Path -Path $prefsPath -PathType Leaf) {
    $prefs = Get-Content -Path $prefsPath | ConvertFrom-Json
    $downloadFolder = $prefs.download.default_directory
}

if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($downloadFolder)) {
    # Chrome is using the download folder set in Windows for the current user

    # read from registry:
    # the Downloads property is stored under Guid instead of friendly name..
    $regPath = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders'
    $downloadFolder = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $regPath -Name '{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}'

    # or use the Shell.Application COM object
    # $downloadFolder = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:Downloads').Self.Path
}

$downloadFolder
```